# Javascript global variable - console log undefined

Tags: javascript, global

I have problem with this line

```
 console.log("xxx" + stanica1);
```

Result is xxxundefined but i need return value stanica1Prosjek/24;

```
function podatciPrethodniDan(handleData) {
  var parametar = $("#parametar1").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/getPreviousDayData.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      parametar: parametar
    },
    success: function(data) {
        handleData(data);
      } //end of success
  }); //end of ajax
}

function style(feature) {
  var stanica1;


  stanica1 = podatciPrethodniDan(function(output) {
    //console.log(output);

    var stanica1Prosjek = 0;
    var stanica2Prosjek = 0;
    var stanica3Prosjek = 0;
    var stanica4Prosjek = 0;

    //console.log(output.length);
    for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
      //console.log("petlja " + i);
      if (i < 24) {
        stanica1Prosjek = stanica1Prosjek + parseFloat(output[i].par);
        //console.log(stanica1Prosjek + " " +  i);
      }
    }
    console.log("in" + stanica1Prosjek);
    return stanica1Prosjek / 24;

  });

  console.log("xxx" + stanica1);

}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're ever calling `stanical`, you're just defining it

Comment: stanica1 = podatciPrethodniDan(function(output) ... ?

Comment: @tcooc not a duplicate, OP is properly using a callback.

Comment: @SterlingArcher From looking at the given code, the OP is trying to return `stanica1Prosjek/24` which is run asynchronously, and save the value to `stanica1` (which is `console.log`ged synchronously). This is not possible without adding an *additional* callback or reworking the code.

Comment: @SterlingArcher well, OP is using a callback but the `console.log` is still immediately after calling the function with the callback in it, so it's still going to be populated when the callback executes which is _after_ that point in time.

Comment: So the OP needs a callback for the callback. ;)

Comment: @epascarello Yo dawg...

Answer (score -1):

Define you var out of functions.
Example:

```
var demo = 12;
function ok () {
    demo += 3;
}


function ok2 () {
    demo+= 5;
}

console.log( demo ); // return 12
ok();
console.log( demo ); // return 15
ok2():
console.log( demo ); // return 20
```

Comment: This is not the issue in question